# Load multiple JavaScript via interop in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor with NET7. I created a component that is a facade of ChartJs and I like to add multiple JavaScript when the component is initialize. At the moment, I defined the [interop file](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorChartjs/blob/6d038d8ca44f370042fb7611b601214d31cb2f30/src/ChartJsInterop.cs#L10) like:

```
private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

public class ChartJsInterop
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    public ChartJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
            "./_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs/Chart.js").AsTask());
    }
}
```

This adds my custom script but I also want to add other scripts (instead of adding them in the *index.html*). So, I tried to do this

```
public ChartJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
        "./_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs/Chart.js").AsTask());

    jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
        "./_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs/lib/Chart.js/chart.js").AsTask();
    jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
        "./_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js").AsTask();
}
```

In this case, the application doesn't find immediately the scripts and returns a lot of errors. After few seconds, the scripts are loaded and the application show the graphs as I expected.

I want to avoid errors. How can I load multiple JavaScript in the `ChartJsInterop`? Is it possible to extend the  `moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(...);` with multiple scripts?

Comment: Well, you haven't shared what errors you are getting.  I see that you are not assigning the 2nd and 3rd imported modules for anything.  If they are supposed to refer to anything (like finding objects by ID etc.) then the DOM will need to be loaded, i.e. you'll need to instantiate your class in OnAfterRender.  I don't know how the `Lazy` keyword works, but if you're having errors, I'm assuming that you are trying to run your import calls before the page is ready to do so.

Comment: The error occurs because JavaScript can't find the `chart.js` library. I added the definition of `moduleTask`

Comment: The spelling of Chart.js and chart.js is inconsistent.  Are you sure that you've correctly typed all the names?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 different files